# Suggestions on using Pi as an audio delay buffer

Tags: raspbian, audio, audio-playback

Trying to find a solution to using a Pi as an audio delay device (in the order of 10 minutes or so).

I have an external analog audio source providing constant audio to the Pi via an external USB soundcard which I want to delay by a fixed amount (we'll say 10 minutes), then output through either same USB soundcard, or a second soundcard. The key would be robustness - this would be running unattended in a server room environment.  Not talking HD audio here, it's ultimately destined for icecast/shoutcast.

Comment: not really a question that is specific to the Raspberry Pi ... search in the Linux realm ... there may be audio delay sofware available ... maybe a better fit at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ or even at https://sound.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you know how to read audio from and write audio to an audio device? That would be the hardest part